# minecraft crashes immediately upon launching

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 307]
[03:56:00] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: TatiCraft07
[03:56:01] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: lastServer:
[03:56:01] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[03:56:02] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[03:56:02] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[03:56:03] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[03:56:03] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[03:56:03] [Thread-5/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[03:56:03] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[03:56:04] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[03:56:12] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting integrated minecraft server version 1.10.2
[03:56:12] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[03:56:12] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[03:56:13] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity Bat that already exists with UUID 4bf9228b-8cb6-4612-b23a-1a66571d21b6
[03:56:13] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 62%
[03:56:14] [Server thread/INFO]: Changing view distance to 12, from 10
[03:56:14] [Server thread/INFO]: TatiCraft07[local:E:3c8fa438] logged in with entity id 210 at (-251.2242340905647, 67.0, -191.09485819462554)
[03:56:14] [Server thread/INFO]: TatiCraft07 joined the game
[03:56:15] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving and pausing game...
[03:56:15] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'New World'/Overworld
[03:56:15] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'New World'/Nether
[03:56:15] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'New World'/The End
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000001b4bbf43, pid=3996, tid=6876
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig75icd64.dll+0x6bf43]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Gail\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid3996.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Please give us some more information, like whether or not you're playing with mods, what version you're running, what version of Java you're using (if applicable), and your pc stats. The more information you give us, the more we'll be able to help

Comment: Hello Gail, in order to get some good answers, try [edit]ing to use the steps written in [this FAQ post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/how-do-i-ask-a-good-minecraft-bug-crash-question) about Minecraft crash questions. Thanks for keeping the quality of this site up.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a problem with a driver for an intel graphics chip. You can try increasing the amount of RAM assigned to your minecraft process, but if that doesn't work, you're out of luck. Then your only option is to get a new computer or graphics card. See this page on the Mojang bug tracker for more info:

https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-32606